# Add a sequence of numbers to divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of 8 divs and need to add a sequence of class numbers to them using Jquery to style them individually. Need to add them to the 'content-block' div see example below.

The desired effect will be something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="content-block" *class="post1"*>
</div></div>

<div class="wrapper">
<div id="content-block" *class="post2"*>
</div></div>
```

I have added the script

```
**Javascript**
$('.post-block').each(function(i){
$(this).addClass('post' + i);})
```

but I need to link them with anchor links so I will need a way to add an ID to the post-block.

```
Desired effect
**HTML**
<div id="post1" class="post-block">
</div>

<div id="post2" class="post-block">
</div>
```

Many thanks

Comment: You can't have same id more than once `content-block`. It should be once per element per page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3aTNY/)

First, you can only use an ID once on a page. You can use classes many times on a page.

Because of this I made `content-block` a class, and I made your various `post1`, `post2`... ids.

The function below will go through [**each**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) of the elements that have the `content-block` class within a `wrapper` class, and it will add an appropriate `id` to each one. For the callback function of `each()` you can make use of the `index` and `value` as arguments. I created a separate `num` variable, since `index` starts at zero.

In the `each` function, you could also use `this` instead of `value`.

The jQuery:

```
$.each($(".wrapper > .content-block"), function(index, value){
    var num = index + 1;
    $(value).attr("id","post"+ num);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$(".content-block").each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass("post" + i);
})
```

Obs: I'm using class selector (".content-block") not id selector ("#content-block").

Answer (score 1):

You are probably confusing unique CSS IDs with classes, which are normally used to give elements a common look and feel. Here's how you would assign unique IDs to all elements within your markup:

```
$('.wrapper').find('div').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('id', 'unique-' + ++index);
});
```

Comment: My only quibble is that this starts at `unique-0` and not `unique-1`, like OP specified, but this is easily solved, but it requires an extra line (eg my answer).... due to the insanity that is `+` concatenation in JS  (`'unique-' + index + 1` doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

If you get rid of the IDs, you could simply do this (assuming there's only one child `<div>` per `.wrapper`.

```
$(".wrapper > div").addClass(function(i) { return 'post' + (i + 1) });
```

This will result in:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="post1"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="post2"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="post3"></div>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you fix the duplicated `id` problem, and you have an outer container object. Then we'd have:

```
$('div#outercontainer').find('div.wrapper > div').each( function(i){
  var postnum = i+1; // remove any possible overloaded "+" operator ambiguity
  $(this).addClass('post'+postnum);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not turn your divs into li, part of a OL element? Semantically more relevant...